# How can I convert all heading text to Title Case with XSLT?

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I have a XML file containing a list of headings that I need to change to title case (words should begin with a capital letter except for most articles, conjunctions, and prepositions) with the help of XSLT.

Example: 
"<h1>PERSONS OF THE DIALOGUE</h1>

in to

"<h1>Persons of the Dialogue</h1>

Please help...

Thanks

Comment: It's doable, but you would need to define explicitly what the list of "most articles, conjunctions, and prepositions" is.

Comment: ' A',' An',' The',' And',' But',' For',' Nor',' Or', ' So',' Yet',' As',' At',' By',' If',' In',' Of',' On',' To',' With',' When', 'Where'

Comment: If these words list will come between the sentence it will be change into lower case.
If these words will be come at the start point then please leave as it is.

Comment: Do the `h1` elements contain nothing but plain text? Or any other elements as well? You can use the `tokenize` function or the `xsl:analyze-string` element (or in XSLT 3 the `analyze-string` function) to break up plain text into tokens separated by a regular expression pattern (`tokenize` with e.g. `\s+`) or made up of a regular expression pattern (e.g. `\p{L}+` for letters) with `analyze-string` and then use `lower-case` and `substring` to convert what you want to convert.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way you could do this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="words" select="'*a*,*an*,*the*,*and*,*but*,*for*,*nor*,*or*,*so*,*yet*,*as*,*at*,*by*,*if*,*in*,*of*,*on*,*to*,*with*,*when*,*where*'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="document/h1"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="h1">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:variable name="elements" select="tokenize(lower-case(.), ' ')"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="$elements">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <!-- The first letter of the first word of a title is always Uppercase -->
                    <xsl:when test="position()=1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(substring(.,1,1))"/>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,2)"/>
                        <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>    
                        </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:choose>
                            <!-- If the word is contained in $words, leave it Lowercase -->
                            <xsl:when test="contains($words,concat('*',.,'*'))">
                                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>    
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <!-- If not, first letter is Uppercase -->
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="upper-case(substring(.,1,1))"/>
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,2)"/>
                                <xsl:if test="position()!=last()">
                                    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>    
                                </xsl:if>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9m/1

Comment: Its working very well but one problem is occurred that If these words will be come at the start point of the heading then leave as it is
Example:
source code:
<h2>THE REPUBLIC</h2>
result code:
<h2>the Republic</h2>
but s/b
<h2>The Republic</h2>

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you want. I thought you always wanted the first letter in the header  to be uppercase. See the example here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/93dFK9m/2